# Reading a file to a dictionary and printing out a value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file with two columns:

```
one uno
two dos
three tres
hello hola
```

I want to read this file into a dictionary and print out the Spanish translation of the English word the user has entered. If the English word is not present then it should print out a "not there" statement. I have some code and but when I run it always prints out "not there" regardless of what I enter. What can I do to fix this? Thanks

```
def spanish(word):
    newDict = {}
    spanishfile = open("eng2sp.txt","r")
    for line in spanishfile:
        (word, val) = line.split()
        newDict[str(word)] = val
        if 'word' in newDict:
            print(newDict['word'])
        else:
            print("Not there")



def main():
    word = str(input("Please enter the English word you would like to translate or enter EXIT to quit: "))
    while word != "EXIT":
        spanish(word)
        word = str(input("Please enter the English word you would like to translate or enter EXIT to quit: "))

main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `spanish()` function, you are naming the argument and local variable with the same name and then you are not checking the argument against your `newDict` but rather the string `word`, which would make perfect sense why you always get `"Not there"`, plus you don't need to `newDict[str(word)] = val`, because you already read it as `string`

Here is your fix:

```
def spanish(word_lookup):
    with open("eng2sp.txt","r") as spanishfile:
        newDict = dict(line.split() for line in spanishfile)
    if word_lookup in newDict:
            print(newDict[word_lookup])
    else:
        print("Not there")
```

Comment: @BobSmith...I updated my answer, it was actually the `for` loop keeps looping until end of file, so I added `return` statement which will exist from your `spanish` function as soon as it finds a match

Comment: That fixes it if I enter "one", but If I enter "two" I still get "Not there" then "dos" or if I enter "three" I get "Not there", "Not There", "tres"

Answer (score 0):

two major problems:

```
if 'word' in newDict:
```

checks if the literal string containing "word" (which it probably isnt) is in your dict. change that to: `if word in newDict: print newDict[word]`

```
(word, val) = line.split()
```

overwrites whatever `word` you passed into your function to equal to each english word in your file. change that to something like `eng,spa = line.split()` or something different to not overwrite the parameter you passed into your function